# Flutter Web Deisgn disturbed on scroll?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am developing Flutter Web. In Debug mode design works fine but when I test it in release mode its design mixed up and get disturbed totally here is the link in Live Mode: https://www.takehair-app.com/#/. Have any one faced issue earlier?[[these are the images in live mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dk8WX.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ugint.png)

This is the fine design in debug mode

Comment: It just looks that a copy of the first child of your scrollable container is also in the background. I would guess it's simply a mistake in your code but it seems weird to me that debug and release has different behaviour. But we really can't judge it or help you without seeing your code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.